# NLTK suddenly not working in anaconda, jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, nltk

When I want to import nltk, this error happens.

[image: Jupyter notebook screen shot]

Be careful, it doesn't say the nltk module doesn't exist, it says it has no download attribute. it used to work just fine, I already uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it. I tried uninstalling nltk package by using pip uninstall, but it takes ages, like hours, and I'm not sure it's actually working, because there are no results even after hours. I'm using windows.

I'm new to programming, in the phase of learning.

Comment: Hi maryam,I would suggest you that first do "import nltk" and that works well then check the version of it and after that try to import download function from that.If that fails then check the alternative of download in that version, may be it has changed.

Comment: hi, but the thing is, I want to import nltk and it doesn't work. It is more clear in the picture